# Why private randomization does not help the Shannon's source coding

Tags: it.information-theory, entropy

I am wondering why stochastic encoder and decoder can not help the Shannon source coding? I know the achievability scheme of source coding, which is based on typicality, is deterministic, and hence we dont need any further randomization, but I want to know what is the reason why further private randomization does not help.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you elaborate on your wisdom on "I know the achievability scheme of source coding, which is based on typicality, is deterministic"?

Answer (score 1):

The question, as it stands, is unclear.

In any case there is *data processing inequality*, which proves that
any further randomization does not increase mutual information.

See e.g. [section 6. from this pdf](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~maivu/ES250/1-entropy.pdf). Or:

- Sec. 2.8 in Thomas M. Cover, Joy A. Thomas, "Elements of Information Theory", Second Edition (1991).